# Filtering pandas dataframe from user input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have successfully pulled a table from a website, but I am wanting to filter it by a list of numbers in different variables that the user inputs.

in basic terms below, as I am still a little new to this all:

( if input = list_1 then filter header 1 (table) by values in list_1 )

Apologies If I have not exampled this clearly enough!

```
import pandas as pd

import ssl

 

list_1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,)                                                                                               

list_2 = (5,6,7,8,9,10)


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

pd.set_option('display.width', None)

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

 
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


dfs = pd.read_html("Some_Wesbite")

 
print(dfs)

 

 

 output:

 

Header 1     |        Header 2 |

 

1                      text  

234                    text

56                     text

23                     text

7664                   text

etc                     etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dfs[dfs['Header 1'].isin(list_1)]
```

If this doesn't work make a minimal reproducible example with what you want.

Edit:

```
list_1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,)
list_2 = (3,4,5,24)
df= pd.DataFrame({'header 1': [2,1,4242,24,22,13], 
                  'header 2': ['a','b','c','d','e','f']})
dic_list = {'list_1':list_1,'list_2':list_2}
mask = dic_list[input("write list_1 or list2")]
df[df['header 1'].isin(list_1)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! unfortunately, that kicked out:

TypeError:list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: it works perfectly... but I add some mere code to make it reproducible, that by the way is how you should formulate the questions, so you make the life easier for people willing to help.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example